# how to close connection using prepare statement in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, php-5.3

I am using php to create the user accounts on server database.I have used prepare statement to create user account.I want to know how can i close my sql connection using prepare statement or i don't need to close the connections? Is it done automatically.

Here is my code

```
public function createUser($name, $email, $password,$file_path,$phone,$address,$profession,$language)
    {


        $response = array();

        // First check if user already existed in db
        if (!$this->isUserExists($email)) {

            // Generating API key
            $api_key = $this->generateApiKey();

            // insert query
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, email, password, api_key,profile_pic,phone,address,profession,language,date) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,now())");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $name, $email, $password, $api_key,$file_path,$phone,$address,$profession,$language);

            $result = $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->close();

            // Check for successful insertion
            if ($result)
            {
                // User successfully inserted
                return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
            }
            else
            {
                // Failed to create user
                return USER_CREATE_FAILED;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // User with same email already existed in the db
            return USER_ALREADY_EXISTED;
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

I am new to php so i don't have any idea about this.

Comment: You're already using $stmt->close(), so everything is fine.

Comment: Ok.It mean i don't have to write like conn->close(); or mysqli->close();

Comment: Your code makes me wonder where the $this->conn is opened, at a similar place in the lifecycle-end of the object you would have to close the connection

Comment: i don't understand what you are saying.Tell me am i doing wrong?If yes then what is the solution.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083341/when-to-call-mysqliclose - You only have to use $conn->close(); IF you wanna terminate the connection before the script is already done.

Answer (score 2):

$stmt->close();

is enough .

check this 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: but in your link they are also using $conn->close();@Manu

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->close(); // Closes the prepared statement

$this->conn->close(); // Closes the mysql connection
```

Comment: In my code i am no where using the keyword $conn i am just using conn.@Mallik.somebody has just answered $stmt>close() is enough.

Comment: what issues can occuer if i don't close the mysql connection ?

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879500/mysqli-do-i-really-need-to-do-result-close-mysqli-close)